# Breakpoint is never hit - is my xdebug not working properly?

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

My NetBeans IDE does ignore breakpoints and does only debug when I use `xdebug_break()`.

---

**Screenshot 1** - `xdebug_break()` set

[image]

The yellow debug arrow is set and I can start debugging by using `Step in`, `Step out` etc. Everything works great.

---

**Screenshot 2** - no `xdebug_break()`

[image]

There is no yellow arrow and I can't debug, I can press `Step into` as many times as I like and it makes no difference.

The "Finish Debugger Session" and "Run to cursor" buttons are grayed out for unknown reasons.

---

It used to work great as I was using XAMPP, but I switched to WAMP and now I run into problems.

xDebug config in `phpForApache.ini`:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="A:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.35/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_log="A:/wamp/logs/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.force_error_reporting = on
xdebug.force_display_errors = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="A:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

`phpinfo()` showed that my config was successfully loaded.

---

I try to debug a project on a virtual host with address `http://csvChart` which is locally on my webserver.

Comment: 1) Show xdebug log 2) Do not set breakpoints on multi-line statements -- due to the way how xdebug/PHP works (how PHP generates bytecode), the actual breakpoint might be somewhere in the middle of multi-line statement. Always try to place them on simple statements. P.S. Jumping between PhpStorm/NetBeans? It's not the tool to blame (IDE) but rather improper configuration of xdebug/IDE from your end (e.g. due to lack of knowledge/information etc)

Comment: @LazyOne, you are right. It works after placing the breakpoint somewhere else. It was not working because the if condition was never true... omg.

Comment: @LazyOne, Im using NetBeans at home and PhpStorm at work, because I can't afford PhpStorm.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. I saw your few tickets and they have different IDEs mentioned .. and thought it was it was "I cannot make it work here .. so it must be an IDE/editor fault" kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the XDEBUG config that I use and it works with WAMPSever and Netbeans

I cannot be sure if this will solve your problem, but it works for me

```
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 400;
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 9000
xdebug.remote_log="d:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the location of the Breakpoint being inside of a condition block which was never entered because the condition was never true. So obviously it can't work.

It works after changing the breakpoint position.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days until I can mark this as solution, so please don't stone me.